# How does this notation work? `object = Object.new [foo]`

Tags: ruby

I saw the code `path = Path.new [edge]` [here](https://github.com/thuss/rpcfn-3-shortest_path/blob/master/lib/shortest_path.rb).

The [`Object.new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Class.html#method-i-new) method in the Ruby docs is not helping me understand.

How does the syntax `object = Object.new [foo]` work?

Comment: @Darshan-Josiah Barber Your edit is change the or enhanced the question to some extent that was not added by OP. OP thought `Class#new` has been called, and if so how does it take argument. But your edit change the question

Comment: @ArupRakshit I don't think I changed the meaning of the question at all; I just added the question from the title into the body... But by all means, if you think I accidentally changed the meaning somehow, you or he should edit it to correct my mistake.

Comment: Joe, there is nothing complex going on here. `Path` is defined as a subclass of `Array`.  Since no `Path#new` method has been defined, `Path#new` invokes [Array#new](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-c-new).  The docs for `Array#new` show that one option is to include an array as a parameter, in which case that will be the value of the new array; for example, `Array.new ['cats'] #=> ["cats"]`.  So here, `Path.new [edge]` is merely creating a new instance of `Path` with a single element, namely, the value of `edge`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually a call as below :

```
 Array.new [12] # => [12]
```

Your `Path` class is a subclass of `Array`. Thus it is calling [`Array::new(array)`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-c-new), from the line you mentioned `Path.new [edge]`.

From the GitHub [lines](https://github.com/thuss/rpcfn-3-shortest_path/blob/master/lib/shortest_path.rb#L7-L12) I took the code as below :-

```
  # Adds distance method to compute the distance of the current path
  class Path < Array
    def distance
      (any?)? inject(0) { | sum, edge | sum += edge[LENGTH] } : INFINITY
    end
  end
```

Here is an example to show it other way. I override the `Array::new` method :-

```
class Array
  def self.new
    12
  end
end

class Path < Array
  # code
end

Path.new # => 12
```

Comment: Are you sure `Array` is overriding `new`? I believe it is overriding `initialize`... https://gist.github.com/jurisgalang/714680

Comment: @UriAgassi Last example, I used to show that `Class#new` has been called. As `Array::new` method exist, it has been called by `Path.new`, as neither `Path::new` has been defined or `Path` class contains any `#initialize` method at all.

Comment: `Array#initialize`?  Maybe [this](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4410995) will help clarify. :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland That was me.. :-) I was nooby ( although still I am) :)

Comment: You have explained the semantics, but the OP is asking about the syntax.